# SQL: One 2 many rows with many rows combined into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

I have four tables, namely `tblProject` (one record), `tblTeamMembers` (many records), `tblProjectStatus` (look-up table) and `tblProjectScoresComments` (many records). I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Below are the table definitions:

**tblProject**:

```
[ProjectID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectName] [NVARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,
[CommunityProblem] [NTEXT] NOT NULL,
[IctSolveCommunityProblem] [NTEXT] NOT NULL,
[TeamMemberRoles] [NTEXT] NOT NULL,
[ProjectImpact] [NTEXT] NOT NULL,
[HelpRaiseFunds] [NTEXT] NOT NULL,
[ProjectStatus] [INT] NOT NULL,
[CaptureDate] [DATE] NOT NULL
```

**tblTeamMembers**:

```
[MemberID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Person] [NVARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,
[SalRef] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
[Email] [NVARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [NVARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,
[TeamLeader] [INT] NOT NULL,
[ProjectLeader] [INT] NOT NULL,
[ProjectLeaderContactNo] [NVARCHAR](150) NULL,
[ProjectID] [INT] NOT NULL
```

**tblProjectScoresComments**

```
[RecID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectID] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Score] [FLOAT] NOT NULL,
[Comments] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
[UserID] [NVARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,
[DateCaptured] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
```

**tblProjectStatus**:

```
[ProjectStatusID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProjectStatus] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL
```

I would like the results to return columns from all three tables, but the 3rd table (`tblProjectScoresComments`) has many records and for the column `[Score]` an average should be returned, and the `[Comments]` column should have all comments returned as 1 column and every comment should be separated by a comma (`,`).

I would like to use a query similar to the below:

```
SELECT 
    p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName AS Project, 
    ps.ProjectStatus, 
    tm.Person AS ProjectLeader, 
    p.CaptureDate, [AVERAGE_SCORE_FOR_ALL] AS Score,  
    [ALL_COMMENTS_MERGED_TO_ONE_COLUMN] AS Comments
FROM
    dbo.tblProject AS p 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblProjectStatus AS ps ON p.ProjectStatus = ps.ProjectStatusID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblTeamMembers AS tm ON p.ProjectID = tm.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tblProjectScoresComments AS psc ON p.ProjectID = psc.ProjectID
WHERE
    (tm.ProjectLeader = 1)
```

Results should look something like this:

```
ProjectID | Project                                                   | ProjectStatus    | ProjectLeader | CaptureDate | Score   |Comments
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | Access to ICT-Makatane High School and Community Project  | Not yet decided  | Mary Ndlovu   | 2019-10-04  | 1.67    |Comment 1,Comment 2,Comment 3
2         | Asample project                                           | Rejected         | Joe Soap      | 2019-11-07  | 3       |Comment 1,Comment 2
```

Would really appreciate assistance!

Comment: Use stuff with xml path()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like aggregation:

```
SELECT p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName AS Project, ps.ProjectStatus, tm.Person AS ProjectLeader, 
p.CaptureDate,
       avg(psc.score) AS avg_score, 
       string_agg(psc.comments, ' ') as Comments
FROM dbo.tblProject p JOIN
     dbo.tblProjectStatus ps
     ON p.ProjectStatus = ps.ProjectStatusID JOIN
     dbo.tblTeamMembers tm
     ON p.ProjectID = tm.ProjectID JOIN
     dbo.tblProjectScoresComments 
     psc
     ON p.ProjectID = psc.ProjectID
WHERE tm.ProjectLeader = 1
GROUP BY p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName AS Project, ps.ProjectStatus, tm.Person AS ProjectLeader, 
p.CaptureDate;
```

EDIT:

The alternative to `string_agg()` is rather messy:

```
SELECT . . .,
       psc.avg_score, c.comments,
FROM dbo.tblProject p JOIN
     dbo.tblProjectStatus ps
     ON p.ProjectStatus = ps.ProjectStatusID JOIN
     dbo.tblTeamMembers tm
     ON p.ProjectID = tm.ProjectID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + psc.comment
                     FROM dbo.tblProjectScoresComments psc
                     WHERE p.ProjectID = psc.ProjectID
                     FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE 
                    ).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'
                           ), 1, 2, ''
                  ) as comments
     ) c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT AVG(psc.score) as avg_score
      FROM dbo.tblProjectScoresComments psc
      WHERE p.ProjectID = psc.ProjectID
     ) psc
```

An outer `GROUP BY` should not be necessary.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response @Gordon. Seem I have my MSSQL version wrong as I get a 'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name. I checked my version and it is SQL Server 2016

Comment: @JohanvDk . . . That's a shame.  The alternative is rather messy.

Comment: @Gordon...I get and error 'Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max)'    Will the query return rows where no match is found in tblProjectScoresComments? I need it to return all rows from the other tables as there will always be a match. When no match is found in tblProjectScoresComments it should just return null for those two columns.

Comment: @JohanvDk . . . (1) I fixed a typo.  (2) I learned that `.VALUE` and `.value` are not the same.  (3) I changed to `OUTER APPLY` to address the missing data that you refer to in your comment.

Comment: Many thanks, it is now working as required after your last edit. I just added the WHERE clause. Enjoy the rest of your day\evening. Much appreciated!